# How do I use the React Native Navigation Stack with class components?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm working on a React Native project and I'm having an issue using the react native navigation stack. I've used it before with functional components but in this particular project I am using a class component and am unsure of how to properly pass in props to do so.

I tried to pass in props to my constructor and use props.navigation.navigate but I received this error.

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation.navigate')
```

I'm sure this is an easy fix but I'm not sure how exactly to pass navigation props to this class.

```
render(){
  return (
    <View style={styles.NoChoresContainer}>
      <View style={styles.LogoPH}><AntDesign name="minussquareo" size={100} color="black" /></View>
      <View style={styles.NoChoresTextContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.NoChoresText}>You have no chores!</Text>
      </View>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback style={styles.NoChoresTextContainer} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('AddChores')}>
        <Text style={styles.NoChoresButton}> 
          <AntDesign name="pluscircleo" size={20} style={styles.AddCircle} /> 
          Add a chore
        </Text>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </View>
    
  );
    }
```

Also here is how I am passing in props

```
class NoChores extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    };
    
  }
```

and here is my stack navigator

```
<NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#FFA06A"
        },
        headerTintColor: "#fff",
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: "bold",
        },
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          headerTitle: (props) => <Title></Title>,
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="AddChores"
        component={AddChores}
        options={{
          headerTitle: (props) => <Title>Add Chores</Title>,
        }}
      />

    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: Try logging the this.props and see if navigation prop is there or not.

Comment: Ah, yes, it is empty. Thanks!

Comment: Now that I understand the what the issue is, I'm not sure how exactly to correctly pass in the props... any ideas?

Comment: you might misconfigured your navigation, verify with official docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the my first component mounted and inside of the stackscreen contains the navigation props. From there, I just needed to pass down the navigation through props to each component rendered until I eventually reached my goal component.

First Component:

```
class Home extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      
    };
  }

    render(){
  return (
    <SafeAreaView styles={styles.Container}>
    <StatusBar style="auto" />
    <View>
    <Year nav={this.props}/>

    </View>
  </SafeAreaView>
    
  );
    }
}
export default Home;
```

Next Component Passing Props:

```
class Year extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    dayShowing:<Day nav={this.props.nav} />,
    };
  }
```

Comment: can you please explain how `useNavigation` hook can be used in a class component?  Where questions is about the class component

Comment: I still want to use the a class component, however the documentation is not providing any examples of how to do so, nor have I found any examples on the internet that have worked. So what I am doing is I am creating a functional component and returning it as a rxjs component. You can see in the code above how I am I'm returning it. I then, in my class component am importing this functional component and including it in my rxjs there